# How to bring the iteration count from main page to its nested partial view in razor

Tags: c#, razor, partial-views

I have a razor page with a nested partial view where I load it from the javascript.

This is how my page looks like (*I've edited the page code to make it shorter for readability*)

```
@model List<HLS.ViewModels.SurveyEditor.DraftFormDto>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
        @for (int i = 0, length = Model.Count(); i < length; i++)
        {
            <div>
                 @Model[i].Name
            </div>
            <div class="tab-content clearfix page-placeholder">

            </div>
        }
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Div with **'page-placeholder'** class is where i load it from javascript for my partial view.

Here is the partial view page that I load it in the above place holder.

```
@model List<HLS.ViewModels.SurveyEditor.DraftFormDto>
<div>
   @for (int k = 0, length = Model[#].DraftSection.Count(); k < length; k++)
   {
     <div>
        @Model[#].DraftSection[k].Text
     </div>
   }
</div>
```

Take note on the '#' symbol.

So is there any way that I can bring the main page iteration index (**'i'**) to replace the `'#'` symbol?

The actual codes actually have multiple nested partial view.

Any suggestion including js is welcomed but of course I would prefer if it can be done in c# razor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@model List<HLS.ViewModels.SurveyEditor.DraftFormDto>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
        @for (int i = 0, length = Model.Count(); i < length; i++)
        {
            <div>
                 @Model[i].Name
            </div>
            <div class="tab-content clearfix page-placeholder" data-count="@i">

            </div>
        }
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

While loading partial view get data-count using $('.page-placeholder').data('count') and create MainDraftFormDtoModel.

Create new model MainDraftFormDtoModel

```
public class MainDraftFormDtoModel {
public int count {get;set;}
public List<HLS.ViewModels.SurveyEditor.DraftFormDto> DraftFormDto {get;set;}
}
```

in partial view pass MainDraftFromDtoModel

```
@model MainDraftFromDtoModel
<div>
   @for (int k = 0, length = Model.DraftFormDto[Model.count].DraftSection.Count(); k < length; k++)
   {
     <div>
        @Model[Model.count].DraftSection[k].Text
     </div>
   }
</div>
```